Why is ColVA a negative XVA adjustment?
The expression for ColVA is usually written as something similar to this:
$ColVA= -\int_{t}^{T} D(t,u) E_{t}\Big[  s_{X}(u)X(u)\Big]du$
Where D is the discount, $s_{x}$ the spread at which the collateral can be reinvested and X the collateral posted. X has a positive sign when the counterparty posts collateral and negative when we are posting it.
If we increase the amount of collateral that the counterparty is posting, X will increase and the ColVA will become more negative (i.e we would be losing more money). Why does it work like this? If the counterparty is posting more collateral we should be able to re-invest it at $s_{x}$ and make profits not losses.
Could anybody explain what am I missing here? Thanks!

Thanks @JanStuller, X would be positive in this case during the whole life of the trade. Also, $s_{x}$ if I have understood it correctly is the spread to which we rehypotecate the collateral (or the difference between risk-free rate obtained after investing it in a different currency and the local risk-free), we would be paying the risk-free to the counterparty and obtaining the higher new rate.

There is a misconception here.  CollVA is a concept that applies only when the counterparty posts non standard collateral (ie bonds, not cash). When a counterparty posts collateral in the form of (say) corporate bonds, you do not have any cash to invest.  In fact, you have to pledge these bonds into the repo market in order to borrow cash.  This is where the spread comes in, because the repo rate for corporates is SOFR + a spread S.  This situation would not occur if the counterparty posted you cash on which you pay them SOFR flat.  Hence the collVA adjustment which is negative and grows if there is more expected non standard collatsral.
